# R: simple plot with varying slope by value of x axis

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R, hopefully someone can help me. I am trying to figure out how to plot a very simple graph (with `plot()`):

y-axis should be `ay <- c(-1,1)` and x-axis should be `ax <- c(0:6)`. I have a vector `v1<-c(0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.6,-0.2,-0.4, 0.2)`, that gives the slopes for each segment on the x-axis (i.e. between 0 and 1, the slope is -0.1, moving from 1 to 2, the slope is -0.3, and so on.).

I simply need to draw a line that goes from 0 to 6 on the x-axis with slopes between the segments given by v2.

Additionally, there should be a separate straight line with slope -0.5 starting from 0, i.e. `abline(0,-0.5)` in the same figure.

This should be something extremely simple, but I just can't get it right. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `plot(0:5, v1, type = "l")` ?

Comment: `v1` has six elements making your x-axis limits dubious,  while `sum(v1)` is `-1.4` making your y-axis limits dubious unless you start at a positive point

Comment: Something like this? plot(v1 ~ seq(0,5,1), xlim = c(0,5), ylim =  c(-1,1), type = "b"); abline(h = -0.50). Although,  slope is a different thing. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I think I thought it wrong above with x-axis 0:5 (edit: 0:6), and using the vector to list the slope coefficients is probably confusing! I only mean that those are values for the slopes between moving along x-axis, not values on y-axis. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: What is the initial `y`-value? I am asking because you need to calculate the `y`-values corresponding to the `x`-values. Your `v1`-vector contains the slopes between successive `x`-values, which needs to be translated into proper `y`-values first.

Comment: the initial y-value is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
x <- 0:6
v1 <- c(0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.6,-0.2,-0.4, 0.2)
```

Note that the slopes are given by the difference in `y`-values over the difference in `x`-values. Since the difference in `x`-values are always 1 for each successive entry in `v1`, it essentially contains the difference in `y`-values. Taking the first entry in `v1` to be `y(x=0)` (see note below), `cumsum(v1)` gives you the `y`-values you need to give to `plot`.

```
y <- cumsum(v1)

plot(x, y, type="l")
```

**Note** that there are seven slope-values in `v1` but only six differences from 0 to 6. If you count, that is 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, and 5-6, which gives six differences. If the first entry is supposed to be a slope, then the range of `x` needs to be reconsidered.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I'm after!

Answer (score 1):

I have not fully understood your problem. In my opinion the range on the x axis should be (0, 6).
Anyway, see the code below. Hope it can help you.

```
v1 <- c(-0.1,-0.3,-0.6,-0.2,-0.4, 0.2)   
plot(0:6, 1+c(0,cumsum(v1)), type="o", ylim=c(-1,1))
abline(v=0:6, h=seq(-1,1,by=0.1), col="gray", lty=3)
```

[image]

Comment: You're correct, I should have put 0:6 in the first place! This is what I was looking for, thanks for you help!